# How to detect if an HTML Element is the root of a React Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way to detect if an HTML Element is the root of any React component in a production app?

I'm not referring to detecting wether an element is the root of **the entire** React application, rather detecting if an element is the root of any component.

To illustrate:

Let's say we have the following React components:

```js
const FooBar = () => {
  return (
    <div className="foobar">
      <span> foo </span>
      <button> bar </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const Container = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <a className="john"> john </a>
      <a> doe </a>
      <FooBar />
    </div>
  );
}
```

That transpiles to the following HTML:

```html
<div>
  <a class="john"> john </a>
  <a> doe </a>
  <div class="foobar">
    <span> foo </span>
    <button> bar </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

In a production deployment, is there a way to do this from a chrome extension (external script)? and how?

```js
const foobarDiv = document.querySelector('div.foobar');
const span = document.querySelector('span');
const a = document.querySelector('a.john');
isReactComponentRoot(foobarDiv); // true
isReactComponentRoot(span); // false
isReactComponentRoot(a); // false
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will continue to be reliable in the future, but something that's worked for a while is to check if it has a `_reactRootContainer` property.

```js
const root = document.querySelector('.react');
const App = () => {
    return <div className="child"></div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, root);

console.log(root.hasOwnProperty('_reactRootContainer'));
console.log(root.querySelector('.child').hasOwnProperty('_reactRootContainer'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I actually wasn't referring to detecting the root of the entire React app, rather detecting if an element is the root of any React component. I just rephrased the question with more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I have this exact need, there is an internal function inside ReactDom that determines if a domNode is a react root or not.

I think the cheeky way to do this would be to see if the domNode has a prop that starts with _react.